# Mozilla WebExtensions contextMenus.onClicked not working

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to develop a WebExtension with a contextMenu for FireFox. Currently I only have two files and no real functionality. The problem that tabs in context menu are created but function on click doesn't seem to work on them even with example code from Mozilla Developer Network.

This is my manifest.json file:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Search in",
"description": "Searches selected text in YouTube",
"version": "1.0",

"background": {
  "scripts": ["ctmn.js"]
},

"permissions": [
  "contextMenus",
  "activeTab"
]
}
```

This is my ctmn.js file:

```
    function onCreated(n) {
if (browser.runtime.lastError) {
    console.log('Error:' + browser.runtime.lastError);
} else {
    console.log("Item created successfully");
}
}

browser.contextMenus.create({
    id: "YouTube",
    title: 'YouTube',
    contexts: ["selection"]
}, onCreated);


browser.contextMenus.create({
    id: "separator-1",
    type: "separator",
    contexts: ["all"]
}, onCreated);

browser.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
switch (info.menuItemId) {
    case "YouTube":
        console.log('tab clicked');
        break;
}
});
```

in console i have error:

Epmpy string for getElementById() in main.91ddfe2b36c3.js:2:7526 mozilla script

```
(function (global, factory) {
  if (typeof module === 'object' && typeof module.exports === 'object') {
    module.exports = global.document ? factory(global, true)  : function   (w) {
  if (!w.document) {
    throw new Error('jQuery requires a window with a document')
  }
  return factory(w)
}
  } else {
factory(global)
  }
})
```

I have added jQuery to my webextension in script and in manifest "background" and "content_scripts" but it seems to still do not see it. I'm not sure if i write correctly path.

[jQuery added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAMVK.png)

Comment: you're using it wrong - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/contextMenus/onClicked

Comment: @Jaromanda X `addListener` added and still does not work

Comment: Browser JavaScript console. Any errors in it

Comment: @Jaromanda X Empty string for getElementById(). in   main.91ddfe2b36c3.js:2:7526

Comment: well, that doesn't look like it's caused by any code you've posted in the question :p

Comment: @Makyen can you look at this please

Comment: nobody can see code you haven't posted!

Comment: oh, I asked if there were any errors in the javascript console - I should've made it clear - any errors that are related to you webextension

Comment: you claim something called "mozilla script" is showing an error - I'd be surprised, `'jQuery requires a window with a document'` - the browser knows nothing about jQuery

Comment: what the ???? is "mozilla script" - does the error occur without your webextension installed? if so, then it is irrelevant.

Comment: it's just one of the https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net scripts, it occurs only with my webextension installed

Comment: How odd, didn't think WebExtensions relied on jQuery

Comment: @Jaromanda X i have added jQuery to my webextension but it still does not see it

Comment: no, don't do that!

Comment: day number 2, still dont know how to solve it :/